# Alternative to MINUS clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am working on some queries in MySQL and I figured out the `minus` clause is not supported.

Is there any alternative for the `minus` clause in MySQL? How can I substract values in a query over another query?

```
select * from A
minus   //This returns a syntax error in the query format
select * from B;
```

`difference` and `except` clauses are not accepted either in MySQL

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results. The answer depends on your actual data structures.

Comment: Here are some options for you. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-minus/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `LEFT JOIN` would be the alternative that you want only if it is based on the equality of all the respective columns of both tables and not just on the equality of a primary key:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM A LEFT JOIN B 
ON A.col1 <=> B.col1 AND A.col2 <=> B.col2 AND .....
WHERE B.primarykeycolumn IS NULL
```

I have used the *NULL safe operator* `<=>` to check for the equality of `NULL` values also.
You could also use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT A.* FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM B
  WHERE A.col1 <=> B.col1 AND A.col2 <=> B.col2 AND ..... 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't support `MINUS` but you could use `LEFT JOIN` instead. Probably something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b on (a.id=b.id)
WHERE b.id is null
```